# CGImageRef getRowBytes return value larger than (width * channels)

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, opencv, cgimage

I'm trying to convert a CGImageRef to an OpenCV cv::Mat.

Everything works fine with 4 channels images, but for grayscale images it crashes because the CGImageRef GetRowBytes function returns a value larger than the mat.step[0] value (which equals width of the image).

For example, I have a 500 pixels wide grayscale CGImageRef and the CGImageGetBytesPerRow function returns 512.

Why is it returning this value ? And how can I create my cv::Mat correctly ?

```
  - (cv::Mat) CVGrayscaleMatWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)image
{
// NSLog(@"%zu", CGImageGetBytesPerRow(image)); -> return 512
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
CGFloat cols = CGImageGetWidth(image);
CGFloat rows = CGImageGetHeight(image);
cv::Mat cvMat = cv::Mat(rows, cols, CV_8UC1); // 8 bits per component, 1 channel

CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(cvMat.data, 
                                                cols, 
                                                rows, 
                                                8, 
                                                cvMat.step[0], // Bytes per row -> return 500
                                                colorSpace, 
                                                kCGImageAlphaNone |
                                                kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault); 

CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, cols, rows), image);
CGContextRelease(contextRef);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

return cvMat;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work. Bytes Per Row must be multiple of 16.

Here is the code:

```
- (cv::Mat) CVGrayscaleMatWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)image
{

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
CGFloat cols = CGImageGetWidth(image);
CGFloat rows = CGImageGetHeight(image);
cv::Mat cvMat = cv::Mat(rows, cols, CV_8UC1); // 8 bits per component, 1 channel

unsigned long rowBytes = cvMat.step[0];
if (rowBytes % 16) {
    rowBytes = ((rowBytes / 16) + 1) * 16;
}

CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(cvMat.data, 
                                                cols, 
                                                rows, 
                                                8, 
                                                rowBytes,
                                                colorSpace, 
                                                kCGImageAlphaNone |
                                                kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault); 

CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, cols, rows), image);
CGContextRelease(contextRef);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

return cvMat;

}
```